# ssh issue on windows 7 (gitbash vs. windows cmd)

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cmd

I am able to use ssh (i.e., for 'git' with heroku or github etc.) through GitBash, but I cannot do the same from Windows cmd prompt on the same machine. What can be the problem? If I recall correctly, it used to work from cmd prompt.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I got both logs: here is last four lines from cmd which are different from 'git bash':

```
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

in case of Git bash: the respective lines are:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/user1/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve user1
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
```

**Resolved**

As hinted by @snemarch, setting following env var solved my problem:

```
set HOME=C:\Users\user1
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting. You can't just say "I cannot do the same". Give some detail

Comment: Sorry, here is  the error.
__
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
----

Comment: How did you generate the logs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using GitHub, from cmd try

```
ssh -v -T git@github.com
```

See the keys that it is presenting. Maybe try from Git Bash also and compare the output.

This could be because %HOME% is not correctly set. Set it to the directory that contains your `.ssh` directory ( and hence the keys)

Comment: I added the logs into my question. I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: It didn't exactly solve my problem, but it gave me a direction. I just updated my question with the resolution.

Comment: @AsadIqbal - As per the resolution, my answer exactly solves it. Didn't I say that `%HOME%` might not be set?

Comment: yeah. When I read your comment for the first time, i felt that you meant %HOMEPATH% which was properly set in my env:
    HOMEDRIVE=C:
    HOMEPATH=\Users\niqbal
  HOME=C:\Users\niqbal

Answer (score 1):

Look at the file paths - "/.ssh/identity", in the case of cmd.exe, is probably not where you've got your SSH keys :). Probably a case of homedir expansion being done when you're on the git-bash, but not on native cmd.exe .

Instead of using cygwin ssh and the regular ssh key files, consider using PuTTY's plink for SSH program and pageant for ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check your system path includes a reference to your git/bin location